# Как на удаленном сервере в неактивном сеансе тестировать графический интерфейс десктопного приложения?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, uiautomation, vnc

Доброго времени суток всем читающим!

Работаю в отделе автоматизации тестирования и на работе поставили задачу тестировать графический интерфейс десктопного приложения.

**Вот по какой схеме планируется запуск тестов:** в Jenkins'е будет настроена автоматическая сборка в заданное время, которая будет загружать из репозитория Гита исходный код с автотестами и сборка будет запускаться на удаленной машине через ноду Jenkins'а, развернутой на этой удаленной машине.

Соответственно автотесты будут работать в неактивном сеансе Windows, то есть без доступа к графической среде Windows, а так как тестировать требуется интерфейс десктопного приложения, то активный рабочий стол просто необходим.

**Внимание, вопрос:** подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ запускать графическую оболочку Windows в неактивном сеансе, без подключения по RDP к удаленной машине?

На удаленном сервере установлена Windows Server 2008 R2. Язык, на котором пишутся автотесты - C#. Среда разработки: Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Может запустить на этом сервере виртуальную машину с полноценным рабочим столом?

Comment: вы не можете запустить UI приложение из под сервиса, вам надо будет всё равно как ло логиниться на машину и запускать тесты или настраивать автологин на сервере и запускать весь Jenkins при логине юзера (чтобы он работал как обычный процесс, а не сервис)

Comment: @VTT Вообще можно было бы попробовать, но тестируемое приложение взаимодействует с оракловой БД и на виртуальной машине неудобно будет разворачивать экземпляр приложения + БД, к тому же это запрещают правила информационной безопасности, так как я использую уже развернутый экземпляр приложения и БД, которыми пользуется вся компания и которые тоже находятся на удаленных серверах. Есть еще система VNC (Vitrual Network Computing) для доступа к удаленному рабочему столу, использующая протокол RFB, правда пока не разобрался как с ней работать.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, нужен загруженный рабочий стол, в неактивном сеансе можно запустить приложение, но вот уже с UI работать не получится. Насчет автологина спасибо за подсказку, надо будет попробовать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за комментарии.